# Resizable divider line in wxpython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I am not sure what they are called, but I would like a resizable divider line, to separate widgets.

I would like something like this (except horizontal):
http://imm.io/bKgf

If you do not know what i am talking about please comment, thanks and sorry for my ignorance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need, maybe, a splitterwindow:

```
import  wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        pan1 = wx.Window(self.splitter, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        pan1.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        wx.StaticText(pan1, -1, "My Left Panel")

        pan2 = wx.Window(self.splitter, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        pan2.SetBackgroundColour("orange")
        wx.StaticText(pan2, -1, "my Right Panel")

        self.splitter.SplitVertically(pan1, pan2, -100)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will exactly meet your needs, but you might have a look at wxPython's [aui module](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.aui-module.html).  There's some demo code on that page that'll get you started, and the [wxPython demo](http://www.wxpython.org/download.php#stable) has some good examples to try out.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is wx.StaticLine. Just create one of those and add it to your sizer with the EXPAND style flag. See http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.StaticLine-class.html for more info.

EDIT: Oh, I think Joaquin's suggestion for a SplitterWindow may be spot on. Note that there a couple other types of SplitterWindows, like MultiSplitterWindow and FourWaySplitter